# Error When Creating SLD

Tags: sld

It generates the following error:

> línea 17: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Se ha encontrado contenido no válido
>   a partir del elemento 'PropertyIsEqualTo'. Se esperaba uno de
>   '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps",
>   http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps ",
>   http://www.opengis.net/ogc ": logicOps",
>   http://www.opengis.net/ogc":FeatureId} '.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
                       xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>asia_cap_por</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>asia_cap_por</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Baja</Name>
          <Title>Baja: 1.00 - 2.00 Kg/cm2</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>valor</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>baja</ogc:Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFAA00</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Name>Media: 2.00 - 3.00 Kg/cm2</Name>
          <Title>Media: 2.00 - 3.00 Kg/cm2</Title>
          <ogc:Filter> 
              <PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>valor</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>media</ogc:Literal>
              </PropertyIsEqualTo>

          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFF73</CssParameter>
                         </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

        <Rule>
          <Name>Alta</Name>
          <Title>Alta: > 3.00 Kg/cm2</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>valor</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>alta</ogc:Literal>
            </PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#4CE600</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>        

        <Rule>
          <TextSymbolizer>
         <Label>
           <ogc:PropertyName>descrip</ogc:PropertyName>
         </Label>
         <Font>
           <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
         </Font>
         <Halo>
           <Radius>3</Radius>
           <Fill>
             <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
           </Fill>
         </Halo>
       </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Welcome the GIS StackExchange. Please check out the "How to ask a question" guide in the Help section: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask For this question, we need a bit more specificity. What is the "it" that creates the error?

Answer (score 3):

Everything in your `Filter` block must be in the `ogc:` namespace, so:

```
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>valor</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>baja</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
```